# Rating star field in a material ui/redux-form framework

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, redux-form

I am working on a react website - with a form frame that uses material ui and redux forms ---

I've got 2 forms rendered on a page with a unique id -- but I don't understand why the rating field is causing the other to change --- it could be because its a material lab component?

- How do I get the rating field stable so it acts just a radio button as such/integer field
- How do I get the stars back to gold in the UI?

//sandbox
https://codesandbox.io/s/quirky-noyce-gbwf7?file=/src/GenericForm/GenericForm.js

[image]

https://material-ui.com/components/rating/

Answer (score 1):

the solution was to ensure that the name on the rating component is unique -- so I've added a uuid on the name at the end

```
  <Rating 
    {...input}
    name={input.name + "-" +uuid()}
    value={parseFloat(input.value)}
    onChange={(e, value) => {            
        input.onChange(value);
        onHandle(input.name, value);
    }}
    defaultValue={0} 
    max={max}
    disabled={disabled}
    precision={0.5}
  />
```